# Error while generating Primefaces Pie Chart

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, glassfish-5

I am trying to generate a Pie Chart using PrimeFaces (V8.0 / 7.0). And below is the demo code. 
**NOTE**- I am running this Demo on Glassfish5

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.primefaces.model.chart.PieChartModel;

@Named
public class PieDemoMBean {

    private PieChartModel model;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        model=new PieChartModel();
        model.set("Red", 25);
        model.set("Green", 25);
        model.set("Blue", 25);
        model.set("Black", 25);
        model.setShowDataLabels(true);
    }

    public PieChartModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }

}
```

and JSF Page

```
<html xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h1>Pi Chart Demo</h1>
        <div>
            <p:chart type="pie" responsive="true" model="#{pieDemoMBean.model}"/>

        </div>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

And finally here is the error log

```
Error Rendering View[/PiDemo.xhtml]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.component.chart.renderer.PieRenderer.encodeData(PieRenderer.java:43)
    at org.primefaces.component.chart.renderer.BasePlotRenderer.render(BasePlotRenderer.java:38)
```

Please advise.

Comment: Has you can see debugging your code, your init method isn't invoked and that's the cause of the NPE. Could you try adding @ManagedBean to your class?

Comment: @MatteoZanini. I am actually using CDI based injection through out the application and not JSF based. Hence the annotation Named instead of ManagedBean. Having said that, I moved the PieChart building code from the init() method to getModel() method and it has worked now. Many thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been resolved now as I made some change to the code and moved the Pie Chart construction from init() method to getModel() method as below-

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){

}

public PieChartModel getModel() {
        model=new PieChartModel();
        model.set("Red", 25);
        model.set("Green", 25);
        model.set("Blue", 25);
        model.set("Black", 25);
        model.setShowDataLabels(true);
        return model;
    }
```

And the new code works perfectly!! (though baffled me as the Managed Bean is RequestScoped and the code in init() method should have worked equally well)